# Can you hide the $_GET values & URL from the user?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I've developed an in-house application that does not have internet access.

I want to be able to just have a user log in and just see the sitesname.net and no URL past that.

Currently they see a long URL with directories, pages & `$_GET` values based on the session and the functions they are doing. I've noticed that a few of them have made book marks with the `$_GET` values intact so they are doing things that should not be able to be done.

I'd like to be able to just hide the directories, pages & `$_GET` values from them.

Is there an accepted way to do this?

The app in built with `php`, `mysql` on an `apache` server.

Comment: $_GET and $_POST values are supplied by the user, so there isn't a way to completely prevent them from interacting with them. The best you can do is to make sure your application always uses $_POST, or always redirect to a URL without parameters when a request is made to one with parameters.

Comment: Use POST instead of GET.

Comment: Http GET requests should not alter anything on the server in your application. When you want to make modifications you should use a POST or PUT method and then on your server do a redirect to a "clean" GET url. With this the user won't be able to bookmark a URL that will cause things to happen when they navigate to it.

Comment: Could this maybe be done with an `apache` Rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one answer to this, because there are different kinds of information that might be in those parameters:

- Form data which causes an action, such as updating the user's preferences. Make sure such forms are written with `method="post"`, which will put the data in the HTTP body (accessible with `$_POST`), rather than the URL (accessible with `$_GET`). Note that this does *not* give you any security, as a savvy user can still read and manipulate the data that's being sent, but it does keep the URL tidy, and prevents users bookmarking a page with an action on it. It's also often useful to redirect the user to a success page (with no POST parameters) once the data is processed, so that clicking "refresh" doesn't attempt to re-send the data.
- Data which needs to stick with the user for their whole visit, but be cleared next time. Use cookies (`setcookie()` to write, `$_COOKIE` to read on the next page). Again, the user can see and manipulate these, but they're easier to manage for data that needs to expire.
- Data which needs to be secret or secure, such as the verified identity of the user. Use a [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php); the session ID is a random string, which should be configured to use a cookie, and the actual data is never sent to the user, just stored on your server in a file named after that random ID.
- Data which tells the server which page to serve the user. This pretty much has to be in the URL, because that's what gets sent from the user's browser to the server; mod_rewrite can't magically make it invisible, but it can make it look nicer. For instance, you can say that whenever the user asks for the page `http://example.com/users/IMSoP`, the server sees the request as though it was for `http://example.com/user_page.php?username=IMSoP`; you can't make that URL not say `IMSoP`, however, else your code won't know whose user page to show.
- Data for transient messages and panels on the page. If you want to get fancy with your UI, you can make heavy use of AJAX to load parts of your page in separate requests, and stitch them together with JavaScript. The URLs of each part are just like a normal URL, but unless they dig into their browser's debug tools, the user won't see those URLs, only the main page that they loaded. At its most extreme, this results in a "single page interface", where you load the homepage, and every other part of the site is just panels pulled in dynamically; this is quite easy technically, but rather tricky to get a site that is easy to use for users, and not just frustrate them with unexpected behaviour and not being able to do "normal" things like bookmark sections.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This give me a bit more to think with. On your 4th point, wouldn't the `GET` values already be sent and processed by the server, therefor a default page could be shown?

Comment: "Already", when? Every request in HTTP is completely separate, so if I type a URL into my browser, the server receives two pieces of information relevant to this discussion: the URL, and the contents of any cookies set against that domain. If I submit a form with `method="post"`, it also receives the values of that form in the body of the request. Your PHP code has to start with those pieces of information, and work out what to display. You can display a "default" page if you like, but to show the page for IMSoP, you need to know that the user wants that page not the one for Monty.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much of an expert in mod_rewrite, but I think you can hide get params by using mod_rewrite. You can use "post" as Http methods and that way you will have a clean url (i.e. no params in your url) and post is secure as well, if you are thinkig of a security.

- GET - Requests data from a specified resource
- POST - Submits data to be processed to a specified resource

For more information regarding GET & POST you can visit these link, they will help you decide in which situation you have to use either of the http methods. Here:

[GET vs POST (Yay! In Tabluar form)](http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET_%28HTTP%29_vs_POST_%28HTTP%29) 
[HTTP Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) 
[PHP Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)